# asp.net references a DLL that runs thread

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, visual-studio, iis, dll

I am new to ASP.NET and I need to develop an application that communicate with a RFID reader.
In order to do that, I have a DLL project which runs a thread that manages the communication with the reader, while a I have another ASP.NET project which manages the user interface.
Those two projects live in the same solution, so the ASP.NET project references DLL project.
At the beginning of the application, my "Global.asax" file initializes the reader (DLL project), running the thread it has inside, and registering some events such as "CardInside" the DLL fires, when a card is inside the reader.
My doubt is if this thread is really running because it does not do anything. I have placed more than one breakpoints in order to see if that part is being run, but nothing stops there.
I have read something about an issue regarding threads an asp.net, but since this thread is not used in a http request:
-is there any problem running a thread in ISS server at the same time as web page?
-Does an aspx.cs file register events fired by another object normally?As if it were not a web application?
-I am using visual studio 2015, could I use DEBUG object to show messages amongst my DLL lines of code?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are issues with running threads inside of IIS that are not requests. When no requests have come in IIS will tear down the AppDomain and that will `Thread.Abort()` the thread you are running your background work in.

You will need to move your code out of IIS and change it in to a actual windows service if you want it running all the time. You then can have your IIS portion talk to the windows service (or vice-versa) to process whatever the web component is.

Comment: So, If I am not wrong, what yo suggest is that I turn my DLL project into a service and then call it from my web app, is that wright?

Comment: I don't know what your web app does, but likely yes that would be the correct thing to do.

Comment: The web app just shows the amount of money inside the RFID card in a textbox, and allows the user to click a button. It is very simple.

Comment: After wrapping my dll with a service, now I have a differente problem. When I call the service, the code is executed correctly, but suddenly I get a message saying tha the subproccess has finished with code 0 (0x00). Is there any problem calling an external DLL from a WCF service?My DLL is tried and tested in a local application, and it works.

Comment: Ask a new question including all the details and the code that calls your external DLL

Comment: Thank you Scott, I tried your solutions and it works.